# mobile css not showing the code

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a strange problem with a WP site, http://dev.turnim.com/clients/b4h/web/ shows ok when i review on desktop, but then when i look at it using my iphone the logo gets cut off on both sides and the background color is a dark brown

I have checked the mobile css and there it seems okj, so for some reason the mobile view is pulling his info from another css, but i can't seem to find the file

I only need to change the background color and the size of the logo - should be 150px x 70px but it shows around 105px width

Unfortunately my Adobe Edge inspect isn't working and by resizing my browser it will not trigger mobile view

Anyone can have a look at it and tell me where this css file is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming from custom.css line 28. Looks like you may be using a plugin to create the mobile version? I'd check there.